# Excel crashing randomly

Tags: excel

I generate over 100 reports daily in Excel, all with extensive VBA code.  Unfortunately, some files are randomly corrupted for no reason that I can define.  Either the file will crash immediately upon open, the user will get the "can't find project or library" error, a bad parameter warning will show, or the workbook will be completely unusable as all VBA functions are frozen.  In the windows log I will usually see a faulting module for VBE7.dll.  I am running Windows 10 Pro, version 10.0.18362 and Excel 64bit with all updates.  I've reinstalled MS Office and Windows with no help.  I've tried various other fixes (registry changes) that did not help either.  This is a random problem as it doesn't happen to every report but it occurs every day to some of them.  All can be repaired by opening in safe mode and recompiling the code but this is not something I can expect users to do nor do they have access to the code (all pw protected).  I've dealt with this issue for the last two years and nothing has worked.  Microsoft has been utterly unhelpful as well.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Additionally, for any true experts out there who could dig into this and find a solution I am certainly willing to pay for your time and expertise.  Thank you.

Comment: We would need more info... like what code is causing crashes (is there some consistent code in these workbooks?), soemthing that makes this reproducible to look into.  It could be so many different reasons.

Comment: Also, what version of win10 are you using?  1903 i believe is current, but you could be using a managed version or an older one like 1809

Comment: The workbooks contain a significant amount of code but none of it is running when the workbook is opened.  The workbooks crash upon opening or one of the errors listed above (assuming all are related).

Comment: Where are you opening the files from?  Network drive, local, SharePoint, etc.?  In all honesty, this is probably outside the scope for this forum.  This may need to be migrated to be able to get an answer, as SO is more focused on fixing specific programming issues.

Comment: Understood, just losing my mind over this and have not found a solution to the random crashing.  I can open one report and it's fine, open it again a moment later and it crashes.  The files are stored locally.

Comment: Have you checked your event viewer when the crash occurs?

Comment: Yes, when the report crashes upon open it states faulting module VBE7.dll, otherwise no errors show up in the viewer.

Answer (score 1):

the error saying "can't find project or library" could be traced using **[ProcessExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)**

That tool will show you what is going on inside MS Excel at the time of opening the file. With luck, you will see what file, dll or complement is not being loaded and throw the error.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you.  I am running this but not seeing anything that can be used to solve this problem.  Will look into this more though, thanks again.